# Symbol available in gdb but missing in objdump/nm output

Tags: linux, gdb, gnu-toolchain

On Fedora 31, I see that gdb knows the symbols of some system binaries, e.g. `main` of `/usr/bin/true`:

```
$ gdb -ex 'set height 0' -ex 'disas main' -ex q /bin/true
Reading symbols from /bin/true...
Reading symbols from .gnu_debugdata for /usr/bin/true...
(No debugging symbols found in .gnu_debugdata for /usr/bin/true)
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000002550 <+0>: endbr64 
   0x0000000000002554 <+4>: cmp    edi,0x2
[..]
```

But `main` doesn't show up in `objdump -d` nor `nm output:

```
$ objdump -d /usr/bin/true | grep '\<main\>'
$ nm /usr/bin/true | grep main
nm: /usr/bin/true: no symbols
$ nm -D /usr/bin/true | grep '\<main\>'
$
```

How come? Is gdb able to read the main `symbol` from some additional symbol table?

When I compile my own binaries with gcc, nm/objdump show the `main` symbol as expected. Also, when I strip such a binary, gdb can't find the `main` symbol, as well.

I assume that rpmbuild calls gcc/strip with some special flags that cause the above behavior. What are those?

Comment: External/split debug information? https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html

Comment: @Hasturkun, this is what I first thought, too - but gdb also prints: `No debugging symbols found in .gnu_debugdata for /usr/bin/true`

Answer (score 0):

> Is gdb able to read the main symbol from some additional symbol table?

Yes: the one contained in the `.gnu_debugdata` section. More info [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/MiniDebugInfo.html#MiniDebugInfo).

> gdb also prints: No debugging symbols found in .gnu_debugdata for /usr/bin/true

GDB says: there are no *debugging* symbols (i.e. ones with file/line info, variable info, etc.). It *doesn't* say "there are no symbols" (i.e. things you would see in `nm` output). In fact, symbols are *raison d'etre* for `.gnu_debugdata` in the first place.

Comment: Ok. Is there some way to tell `nm`/`objdump` to display/use  those symbols contained in the `.gnu_debugdata` section?

Comment: Yes: `eu-readelf -Ws --elf-section /usr/bin/true`. Please also read the answer that this has been marked a duplicate of.